# How do I cancel a -1 vote without give a +1 vote?

Tags: support, voting

I want to remove a down vote to make it a non-vote but I don't seam to be able to without upvoting? Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

Unclick the down arrow. Also there is a time limit after which votes are locked in unless the post is edited (30 minutes I believe).

Comment: Thanks did not know that. Locked now. Looks like if he edits his answer I will be able to unclick it.

Comment: @DavidAllanFinch Since you have edit privileges, you can also just look for typos and other trivial fixes to make. I use this sparingly since it unlocks everyone's votes, but when it's clearly to the answerer's benefit I'll do it to change a down-vote to a non- or up-vote.